# Конвертер валют с курсом валют из интернета

Tags: конвертер, c++

Здравствуйте! Возможно данная тема обсуждалась, но я пока не нашёл нужного решения. Простенький конвертер валют создать могу, но хотелось, чтобы было обновление курса через интернет. И тут я не знаю как подступиться. Не работал с компонентами интернета в с++. Как вариант обдумывал идею базы данных и отображения в ней списка курса валют, либо ComboBox.

Помогите разобраться, не по лени спрашиваю, а ради понимания. В интернете не нашёл ничего достаточно конкретного. Буду рад хоть ссылке на информацию или книгу. Но лучше конечно на примере.

Comment: У вас, я так понял, настольное приложение на c++. Говорю сразу, с этим языком я не знаком, так что могу неправильно посоветовать)) . Найдите какой-нибудь сайт, какой дает необходимое вам api (курс валют) и погуглите, как организовать работу вашего приложения с этим api. Может ниже кто-нибудь более детально напишет.

Comment: Ну у вас и проблемы! «Либо использовать базу данных, либо комбобокс.»

Comment: @Liam92, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Лет 100 назад писал похожую хрень на основе выдачи сайта [XE.com](http://www.xe.com) - парсил выдачу сайта и размещал на своей прожке. Народ активно юзал, закачки шли - все было хорошо, до тех пор пока не получил предупреждение от юристов xe.com о том, что я нарушаю авторские права. Пригрозили судом и предложили использовать коммерческую RSS выдачу. В общем в итоге пришлось свернуть всю деятельность.

Мораль сей басни: важен легальный источник данных. Либо в виде API или RSS выдачи или веб-сервиса.